# Python Numpy: Raíz impar de números negativos

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Python retorna un número complejo cuando intentamos calcular una raíz impar de un número negativo:

```
>>> (-3)**(1/3)
(0.7211247851537043+1.2490247664834064j)
```

En el módulo `numpy` tenemos la función `numpy.cbrt` que soluciona ese problema para raíces cúbicas:

```
>>> np.cbrt(-3)
-1.4422495703074083
```

¿Existe alguna función para calcular raíces mayores que 3 que retorne un número real cuando el índice es impar y el radicando es negativo?

Comment: En realidad la potencia 1/n de un número cualquiera tiene n soluciones complejas (de las cuales sólo una tiene parte imaginaria = 0 cuando n es impar). ¿No te interesan nunca las soluciones complejas? ¿Sólo las reales?

Comment: Sí, quería apenas las soluciones reales.

Answer (score 1):

Como indiqué en un comentario, un número elevado a `1/n`, para `n` entero, tiene siempre `n` soluciones. Si `n` es impar, sólo una de esas soluciones será real, y las restantes tendrán una parte imaginaria (da igual si el número era positivo o negativo).

Si no estás interesado en las soluciones complejas, a la hora de calcular la raíz `n`-ésima de `x` lo más sencillo es simplemente quitarle el signo a `x`, calcular la raiz, y volver a poner el signo al resultado.

Esto lo hace el siguiente código:

```
import math

def raiz_n(x, n):
  return math.copysign(abs(x)**(1/n), x)

print(raiz_n(-3, 3))
print(raiz(1, 4))
```

```
-1.4422495703074083
1.0
```

Si estuvieras interesado en todas las soluciones, reales y complejas, el código podría ser éste:

```
import cmath

def raices_n(x, n):
  a = cmath.exp((1./n)*cmath.log(x))
  p = cmath.exp(1j*2*cmath.pi*(1./n))
  return [a*(p**i) for i in range(n)]

for c in raices_n(-3, 3):
  print("{:f}".format(c))

print()

for c in raices_n(1, 4):
  print("{:f}".format(c))
```

```
0.721125+1.249025j
-1.442250+0.000000j
0.721125-1.249025j

1.000000+0.000000j
0.000000+1.000000j
-1.000000+0.000000j
-0.000000-1.000000j
```

Comment: Sí, yo estaba haciendo lo siguiente:

`def nraiz(x, n):`
    `if n % 2 != 0:`
        `raiz = numpy.abs(x)**(1/n)`
        `return raiz * numpy.sign(x)`
    `else:`
        `return x**(1/n)`

El único problema que veo en tu función es que si n fuera par retornaría valores negativos para x negativos. 
Yo estaba más curioso por saber si existía alguna función del propio módulo para resolver esos cálculos.

Comment: @AleD Bien visto lo de los negativos con potencias pares. No existe función en la biblioteca estándar, ni tampoco en numpy que yo sepa (ni que google sepa tras las búsquedas que he hecho).

Comment: Lamantablemente no tengo reputación suficiente para dar un up en tu respuesta. Pero te agradezco igualmente.

Comment: @AleD en las respuestas a tus preguntas deberias poder votar, y aceptarlas si son correctas.

Comment: @gbianchi, cuando voto, me sale un mensaje de que preciso 15 puntos, como tengo 5 no me deja...